# Override session with spring security 3.1

Tags: spring-security, session-management

I am using spring security 3.1 and I want to implement a session override feature. If a user logs into the application and if he tries to login again (say a different browser), then he should be redirected to a page which asks him if he wants to kill his previous session and continue. This should come because the max number of sessions allowed would be 1 per user.
I am not sure how to hook this functionality in ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.